# fct_recode replace level by NA

Tags: r, forcats

I am trying to substitute all "a" in a R factor variable by a NA character using forcats::fct_recode. This is what i tried:

```
fct <- forcats::as_factor(c("a", "b"))
fct %>% forcats::fct_recode("c" = "a") #works
fct %>% forcats::fct_recode(NA = "a") #error
fct %>% forcats::fct_recode(NA_character_ = "a") #error
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal with fct_recode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use backticks to turn the values to `NA` :

```
x1 <- fct %>% forcats::fct_recode(`NA` = "a") 
x1
#[1] NA b 
#Levels: NA b
```

However, note that although this "looks" like `NA` it is not real `NA`. It is string `"NA"`.

```
is.na(x1)
#[1] FALSE FALSE

x1 == 'NA'
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

To make it real `NA` replace it to `NULL`.

```
x2 <- fct %>% forcats::fct_recode(NULL = "a")
x2
#[1] <NA> b   
#Levels: b

is.na(x2)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na_if`

```
library(dplyr)
fct %>%
   na_if('a') %>% 
   droplevels
#[1] <NA> b   
#Levels: b
```

Comment: This is risky in some circumstances - it throws an error when `'a'` is not a level of fct. It seems safer to use a forcats function that is intended to deal with factors.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative `forcats`-solution is to use `fct_na_level_to_value` which is explicitly designed for this problem:

```
fct %>% forcats::fct_na_level_to_value("a")
```